# What is the best way to store app data and load it in app?

Tags: android, database

This is just a information question. I'm new to Android app development and currently I'm working on my first app and and it is ready for the release. Now I'm concerned about how to handle heap of users and where to save all their details my app is a service booking app so it needs to save all the order details products details and lots other stuff.

Currently I'm using cloud firestore to load and save all the data of app. But I'm having some issues like without authentication it won't allow users to access some of my data and other. I wonder how large apps save their data and load them perfectly.

I wish someone will help me how can I save all my app data and load them perfectly in app. And  suggest me for a best way to manage large user base. And other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, firestore is good option if you don't have complex backend logic on the database. For simple CRUD operations on data firestore is a good choice but as you said you have a bulk of data then you must go for the Backend database and then connect your database with Rest API. So that all your complex queries will be done on the backend and you can simply consume your API in the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of data from different users, maybe you should use a central server(DB), something like Postgres or MySQL should work fine.

At the same time, you can also do some sort of caching to accelerate the fetching process, like create a small database locally(you can use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)) to store some user specific data.

Comment: I really like firestore to store my product details as it makes easier to update at real time and easier code in the app to. But some other details like user details, user orders and other are a bit messy when stored in firestore. For example i want to know all the orders to be tabulated that are done by different users and other but I'm unaware of that. How can I handle this.